# What is the best way to solve the conflict of mine between ore and rubymine

Tags: rubymine

According to [this](http://rubydoc.info/gems/ore/0.10.0/frames) I need to use <kbd>mine</kbd> to create a project template. But when I use it, Rubymine starts.

What is the best way to avoid this conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the already created command line launcher for RubyMine (`/usr/bin/mine` or whatever path you have chosen), then create a new command line launcher with a different name using `Tools` | `Create Command-line Launcher`.